# Jquery selectmenue onclick firing for every selectmenue in table

Tags: jquery

I am using the jquery selectmenue.
selectmenue one populates dinamicly after the table is binded when a user clicks on it
and selectmenue two populates based on selectmenue one.

i was trying to use the click event for the selectmenue (because i have to fetch the data from the backend with ajax) but the event is being fired for every selectmenue in every row.
Ho can i only fire one event per selectmenue per row?

```
<table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Collection Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Facility
        </th>
        <th>
            Catagory
        </th>
        <th>
            Test
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td>
        May 14 1984
    </td>
    <td>
        JHH
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="catagorySelect" name="catagorySelect">
            <option value="55327">Select All</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="testSelect" name="testSelect">
            <option value="55327">Select All</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        April 14 2006
    </td>
    <td>
        JHH
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="catagorySelect" name="catagorySelect">
            <option value="55327">Select All</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="testSelect" name="testSelect">
            <option value="55327">Select All</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

$('body').on('click','#catagorySelect-button',function(e){

var url = '<%= Url.Action("GetCatagoryListDropDown", "Document") %>';
var contextKey=$('select#catagorySelect').val();

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { contextKey:contextKey },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
         var options = []; 
                    $.each(data, function(i, el) {
                       options.push("<option value='"+ el["Value"] +"'>"+ el["Text"] +"</option>");

                    });

                      $('select#catagorySelect').append(options.join("")).selectmenu();

                }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$('body').on('click','#catagorySelect-button',function(e){
```

to this:

```
$('#catagorySelect').on('click', function(e) {
```

which is (approximately) the same thing as

```
$('body').on('click', '#catagorySelect', function(e) {
```

In your original code you are attaching this event handler to all click events on the `body` (so basically any click anywhere) and filtering by `#catagorySelect-button` which is not an ID that is found anywhere on the page.  My change attaches it only to your select box with ID `#catagorySelect` (the second example binds it to `body` and filters by `#catagorySelect`).

However, you should be using classes, not IDs, as it is not valid to have multiple versions of the same ID.  In that case just change the `id=` attribute to `class=` and replace the `#` in the selectors with `.` - IDs are ONLY for unique elements and you should **never** have more than one of them on a page.  That is what classes are for.

Also, please use spellcheck for the love of god.

Comment: You've only stated the obvious. The ids were intentional. And the  selectbox would not work because the id '#catagorySelect' is an id for the standard combobox not the jquery selectbox. But i thank you for the spelling lesson.

Comment: In that case, I don't really understand what your question is I guess.  And intentional or not, invalid markup is invalid markup.  I think your issue is related to event propagation though, try playing with `e.stopPropagation()` in your click event (or targeting different selectors).